# Large Image overflows the post when inside a blockquote

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, images

I just noticed, while writing an answer, that if I put a larger image inside a `blockquote` it overflows.

Here is an example:

> [image: SS]

That happens because the `blockquote` has `padding:10px`.

Comment: This is a known bug. I don't know if there's anything on MSO that's a duplicate, but there's definitely something on MSE that addresses this.

Comment: Is there a reason you need an image that large in an answer? Seems like you should narrow the answer down to what's needed and include a link to the image or the page where the image resides.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan was a Screenshot, plain and simple, I linked the page of course and quoted part of it. including the image

Comment: This seems like a bug for something that shouldn't happen in the first place, in my opinion. The answer should be able to stand without the image, or with a cropped/smaller version of the image if absolutely necessary, with a link to the full size image, or to the original page, as in this case.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143973/images-can-be-pushed-outside-the-boundaries-of-a-post-by-using-nested-lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images [now have a max-width of 100%](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143973/images-can-be-pushed-outside-the-boundaries-of-a-post-by-using-nested-lists) so they cannot expand outside of whatever nested element contains them.

Comment: Good to know that ;) Apparently reminding this issue ( I didn't know was mentioned 3 years ago in MSE) helped to fix it ;)

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be reduce the `max-width:660px` but just inside the `blockquote`, something like:

```css
.someclass blockquote img {
 max-width:635px /* or other value */
}
```

Alternatively  we can add some letters in front of URL,

**Original url:** `https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj6Zh.png`

**Modified url**  `https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj6Zhm.png`

Example with `m`

---

> [image: SS]

Full table:

```
s: small   square     90×90   (forced)
b: big     square     160×160 (forced)
t: small   thumbnail  160×160
m: medium  thumbnail  320×320
l: large   thumbnail  640×640
h: huge    thumbnail  1024×1024
```

Comment: This doesn't fix [nested lists and blockquotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143973/images-can-be-pushed-outside-the-boundaries-of-a-post-by-using-nested-lists) though.

Comment: @animuson, you are right, `max-width:100%` would be the best solution, but I did mention `/*or other value  */`