# Large image nested in a <kbd> tag overflows, in Firefox only

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

I came across [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276227/why-is-the-i-in-the-title-to-question-26789031-causing-the-formatting-of-the-o), and it looked bad, since the image overflows to the right (I've edited and fixed it now). If I remove the `<kbd>  </kbd>` tags surrounding the image, It *is* sized properly.

Here's a demo of the problem:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

This is somewhat similar to [Large Image overflows the post when inside a blockquote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323304/large-image-overflows-the-post-when-inside-a-blockquote), which is marked as being fixed.

Can this be fixed too, since quite a few people seem to wrap images in `<kbd>` ? I believe this was working correctly before the recent change in styling. I'm using Firefox 45, and this **does not happen in Chrome**.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Firefox 46.0.1 - possibly a glitch in that specific version? Have you tried a hard refresh to make sure you have the latest stylesheet loaded on Firefox?

Comment: Indeed, I also cannot reproduce this in the latest version of FF - should I delete this question, @animuson ?

Comment: I have to ask...why would you put an image in a `kbd` tag? I can't find the "image" key on my keyboard.

Comment: @Paulie_D Because it makes the image stand out: [How to make images stand out when posting images with whitespace?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270195)

Comment: So you're misusing the tag and are surprised when it's buggy? I'd file under *"Will Not Fix"*!