# Image is not being resized appropriately on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: bug, internet-explorer

I am using Internet Explorer version 11.0.9600.18762.  When I view certain questions in Meta Stack Overflow, such as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363902/moderation-queue-priority-concerns), large images expand into the sidebar, which makes things almost impossible to read.
[image: large image covers entire screen]

Comment: **Please don't downvote plausible bug reports.** Ton of changes to styling have been rolling out regularly of late, and making anomalies harder to find just hurts everyone.

Comment: [Reproduced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72B21.png), awesome!

Comment: Ok, looks like it's the `<kbd>` element at fault here. I have no idea why those images were in kbd elements, but that's what did it.

Comment: Nice find.  Not seeing the issue anymore.

Comment: They made an IE 11? I thought they killed IE at version 10 to promote Edge.

Comment: @user2357112 [No, there was an IE 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer#Internet_Explorer_11). They killed it with Version 12 aka Edge, for examle on [Can I use... the first Edge Version has the number 12](https://caniuse.com/#search=html5) (You need to click the button "Show all" in order to see it)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325516, and also related because this is probably the reason why the image was in a `<kbd>` in first place: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270195

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The post has been edited now, but you can view [the original revision in all its glory](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/363902/1). The kicker here is that the images were wrapped in `<kbd>` tags, which are defined as inline blocks with neither width nor max-width - so IE just lets 'em get bigger and bigger to fit their content.

You can reproduce this with text as well:

<kbd>The quick brown foxes jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown foxes jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown foxes jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown foxes jumped over the lazy dog.</kbd>

This should demonstrate the problem in both IE *and* Chrome *and* Firefox. Probably Safari too.

Solution: don't wrap big things in `<kbd>`

Comment: My hunch: the user tried to add a border to their images. Also, [alternative solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kpFS.png): `max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` on all `kbd` elements.

Comment: Welp, it's even reproduced with SE Android app on this answer :)

Comment: [Somewhat related bug report on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58760/kbd-yes-still-kbd-doesnt-play-nice-with-lists) (and [the fix for that bug in SOUP](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/2f696f04029e056ec605725616f6c50c82e78d78/SOUP.user.js#L104), which also fixes this issue as a side effect).

Comment: The line wraps properly in Edge.

Comment: Not for me, it doesn't.