# Ask a question wizard is unusable on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: bug, internet-explorer, ask-question-wizard-2018

When trying to use the [Ask a Question Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard) using Internet Explorer 11, the Tags and Review pages expand and shrink constantly, *much* quicker than the animated gif below, making it unusable.

[image]

[image]

Although IE11 is not supported fully, it is valid to report Internet Explorer bugs; please see these questions:

- [Image is not being resized appropriately on Internet Explorer 11](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363914/image-is-not-being-resized-appropriately-on-internet-explorer-11)
- [Should the [Internet Explorer] tag be removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319643/should-the-internet-explorer-tag-be-removed)
- [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: it's bydesign. It's meant to hypnotize you and to convince you to stop using IE ...

Comment: I'd conjecture that, because it no longer works, IE11 support no longer fits under the "because it works" umbrella and would be eligible to have support removed for it. But that's just me and my long-standing desire to see IE finally removed from support from major websites.

Comment: I'd love to, but because of my company's strict policies, IE11 is the only browser that can be used on Windows 7.  Some of our employees have been moved to Windows 10, but I have not.  This is keeping me from trying out the Ask a Question Wizard.

Comment: @KyleWilliamson SO is not to blame for your company's stifling policies. That said, you being unable to use a resource that's critical for your work is valid grounds to ask for an exception. Because, y' know, it costs the company money in your dropped productivity and all that.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Understood. However, I am guessing with the over 1,000,000 users on Stack Overflow, I'm probably not the only person who will experience this issue. There have been several bugs reported for IE11 that have been fixed recently.

Comment: @Makoto so it was you who [killed my beloved IE6](http://www.ie6death.com/)?

Comment: [Previously reported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381685/366904), although it seems they slowed down the shaking.

Comment: @CodyGray Nice catch.  I searched for questions before posting this, but didn't see that it had already been reported as an Answer to that post.  What I am experiencing is the same epilepsy inducing clip on the previously reported answer.  Should I remove this post because it is technically a duplicate?  Or keep it because it the first time it has been brought up as a question?

Comment: @CodyGray To be clear, the shaking has not slowed down

Comment: Oh, I see. You just slowed down the animated GIF to avoid giving everyone *else* a seizure. How kind of you. Yeah, for feature announcements, we sometimes do this weird thing on Meta where the answers to the feature announcement "question" are additional feature-requests and bug reports related to the new feature. It's up to you whether to keep it or not. This is a valid bug report on its own. On the other hand, it probably doesn't hurt anything to mark it as a duplicate of the official feature announcement, since it's not like you're looking for answers from the community.

Comment: @rene:  Yes, and I would do so again, **unapologetically**.  I've worked a role where we had to support IE5 and Firefox 2.  Let that sink in.  Seeing IE6 die is joyful in comparison.

Comment: Confirm: The actual flashing frequency is the same as your display (for me, 120 Hz).

Comment: Contact Microsoft and ask what they plan to do about it.

Comment: It should stop doing that when you resize the window.

Comment: This appears to be fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed.  I can't reproduce it at this time.